# adding dummy values and use it to get percentages on a separate column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get percentages of categorical data in separate column in order for me to use it to plot a graph
here is my code example

```py
def sanitation(df):
    df=df[["1_Have_a_waste_pit","2_Scatter","3_Put_in_garden","4_Burn","5_Organised_garbage_collection_point",
    "6_Give_animals","7_Other"]]

    df=pd.get_dummies(df).sum().reset_index()
    df=df.rename({"index":"waste management",0:"SubTotal"}, axis="columns")
    return df
```

this gives me this output
[image: results output]

I have tried using value_count() but i dont get desired results of percentages
this is what am expecting
[image: expected output]

Comment: `df['%'] = df['SubTotal'].div(df['SubTotal'].sum()).mul(100).round(2)`